# vim spell checking

Tags: spell-checking, spelling

I am using vim and latex to produce documents and I have realized that I am making a number of spelling mistakes and in order to correct that I installed `vim-lexical` plugin. However, nothing seems to happen. I have the following in my `.vimrc.`

```
let g:spellfile_URL = 'http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell'                                                                                                                         
let g:lexical#spelllang = ['en_us','en_gb','ro_RO']                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                      
augroup lexical                                                                                                                                                                      
  autocmd!                                                                                                                                                                           
  autocmd FileType markdown,mkd call lexical#init()                                                                                                                                  
  autocmd FileType latex call lexical#init()                                                                                                                                         
augroup END
```

To make matters a bit more interesting, I have to produce documents in Romanian and English (not at the same time) and I would like a way to highlight spelling mistakes in both languages.

What do I have to do to make this work? I have looked at `spelllang` documentation but I don't understand it.

Why don't I get any highlights in either English or Romanian with my current setup?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Romanian language. But for English spellchecking you need not install anything. Just make sure that your .vimrc contains the following lines:

```
" Toggle spell checking on and off with `,s`
let mapleader = ","
nmap <silent> <leader>s :set spell!<CR>
```

So when you press ,s all mistakes will be highlighted. Place the cursor on the highlighted word and press z= and select the correct word. To get out of spellchecker press ,s again.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you! it works for Romanian too! if you don't mind, do you also know if this can be integrated with something like [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and get spelling suggestions on the fly? am I asking too much?

Comment: @lucian try `:help spell`. The command `z=` gives suggestions

Comment: thank you! i got it now!